# Absolute div targets parents parent

Tags: css, position

Simple question, hard answer to find.

So I have 3 div's.

```
    <div style="position: relative;" class="div-1">

        <div style="position: relative;" class="div-2">

            <div style="position: absolute;" class="div-3">

                Target Div-1's position relative.

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

The third div is absolute positioned, but it targets the direct parent: div-2. I want it to target div-1. How can I achieve such thing?

Comment: Simple, you can't unless you remove `position:relative` from `div-2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**MDN's docs on POSITION**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) states:

> **absolute**
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

So, the answer is not hard to find... It can't be done in this structure.

The only way would be if the closest positioned element was the first div:

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="div-1">
    <div class="div-2">
        <div style="position: absolute;" class="div-3">
            Target Div-1's position relative.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you cannot change the HTML, maybe override it with the css class:

```
.div-2 { position: initial !important; }
```

Comment: Too bad that's not possible with a CMS generated module. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You may override it in css. Maybe `.div-2 { position: initial !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Because div-2 is relative, the third div will absolute position itself relative to its parent container. If you want to position it relative to div-1, you will need to move it out of div-2 and into div-1.

Remember that when you absolute-position an element, it will not displace its sibling elements, so the positioning of div-2 will not be affected by making div-3 its sibling as long as div-3 is absolute positioned.